# Why following-sibling finds an element inside the current element and not the following one?

Tags: xpath

The xpath `//div[@id='search']/div/div/div[1]` finds the first yellow `div`. I want now to find the following element on the same level (in this case it's the `div`).

I tried appending `//following-sibling::div[1]`, meaning `//div[@id='search']/div/div/div[1]//following-sibling::div[1]`, but it finds the `div` inside that yellow div and not the following one. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Does this help - `//div[@id='search']/div/div/div[1]/following-sibling::div`    -   // means to select all elements at or beneath the context node whereas / introduces an absolute location path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to append `/following-sibling::div` not `//following-sibling::div`.

It's very rarely appropriate to use `//` with any axis other than the child axis, or perhaps the attribute axis. The definition of `//` is that it expands to `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, which explains why `//following-sibling::div` is selecting downwards.